# Isosurface Texturing Issue

Tags: camera, directx, pixel, hlsl, shader

I'm currently having a problem texturing a mesh that is generated using a marching tetrahedron algorithm. The code is in a .fx HLSL file.
A description of the problem could be that the texture seems to move in accordance to the positioning of the camera. So for instance, if the camera is strafed left and right, the texture will also move left and right with it. The problem also occurs when panning the camera left and right.

It is a strange effect, and one that is quite hard to describe, so I have attatched some images, with the texture AddressU and AddressV set to Clamp so it is easier to demonstrate the problem.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GksUW.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpgmV.png

As you can see, moving the camera to the right also moves the texture to the right.

I might have missed something completely obvious, like multiplying by a certain matrix (I've tried). Any help at all would be appreciated.

Here is my pixel shader code.

```
float4 DiffusePS( SurfaceVertex IN ) : SV_Target
```

{

```
float4 AmbientColor = float4(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
float AmbientIntensity = 0.2;

float4 Kd = 0.5;
float4 diffuseLight = 0.5;

float4 Pos = GetWorldSpacePos( IN.Pos );
float3 N = normalize(IN.N);
float3 L1 = normalize(LightPos1 - Pos.xyz);
float3 L2 = normalize(LightPos2 - Pos.xyz);
float3 L3 = normalize(LightPos3 - Pos.xyz);

float NdotL1 = max(0, dot(N, L1));
float NdotL2 = max(0, dot(N, L2));
float NdotL3 = max(0, dot(N, L3));

float3 I = normalize(Pos.xyz);
float3 V = normalize(-Pos.xyz);

float4 vDiff = diffuseLight * Kd * NdotL1;
float4 vDiff2 = diffuseLight * Kd * NdotL2;
float4 vDiff3 = diffuseLight * Kd * NdotL3;

float3 Color = vDiff + vDiff2 + vDiff3;
float4 derp = rockTexture.Sample(RockSampler, IN.tex.xy);

return lerp(derp ,float4(Color, 1), 0.5);
```

Thanks for any help

EDIT: The rest of the .fx file

```
#define MAX_METABALLS   400
#define IOR             2.5

#define PI 3.1415

Buffer<float4> SampleDataBuffer;

struct SampleData
{
    float4 Pos : SV_Position;
    float4 Field : TEXCOORD0;   // Gradient in .xyz, value in .w
};

struct SurfaceVertex
{
    float4 Pos : SV_Position;
    float3 N : NORMAL;
    float2 tex : TEXCOORD;
};

cbuffer constants
{
    float R0Constant = ((1.0 - (1.0/IOR)) * (1.0 - (1.0/IOR))) / ((1.0 + (1.0/IOR)) * (1.0 + (1.0/IOR)));
    float R0Inv = 1.0 - ((1.0 - (1.0/IOR)) * (1.0 - (1.0/IOR)))/((1.0 + (1.0/IOR)) * (1.0 + (1.0/IOR)));
};


cbuffer cb0 : register(b0)
{
    row_major float4x4 ProjInv;
    row_major float3x3 ViewIT;
    row_major float4x4 WorldViewProj;
    row_major float4x4 World;

    uint NumMetaballs;
    float4 Metaballs[MAX_METABALLS];    // .xyz -> metaball center, .w -> metaball squared radius

    float3 ViewportOrg;
    float3 ViewportSizeInv;

    float3 LightPos1;        // view-space light position 1
    float3 LightPos2;        // view-space light position 2
    float3 LightPos3;        // view-space light position 3


};

Texture2D rockTexture;

SamplerState RockSampler
{
    Filter = MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR;
    AddressU = Wrap;
    AddressV = Wrap;
};



float4 GetWorldSpacePos( float4 WindowPos )
{
    float4 ClipPos;
    ClipPos.x = (2 * ((WindowPos.x - ViewportOrg.x) * ViewportSizeInv.x) - 1);
    ClipPos.y = (-2 * ((WindowPos.y - ViewportOrg.y) * ViewportSizeInv.y) + 1);
    ClipPos.z = ((WindowPos.z - ViewportOrg.z) * ViewportSizeInv.z);
    ClipPos.w = 1;

    float4 Pos;
    Pos = mul(ClipPos, ProjInv);    // backtransform clipspace position to get viewspace position
    Pos.xyz /= Pos.w;               // re-normalize


    return Pos;
}


// Metaball function
// Returns metaball function value in .w and its gradient in .xyz
float4 Metaball(float3 Pos, float3 Center, float RadiusSq)
{
    float4 o;

    float3 d = Pos - Center;
    float DistSq = dot(d, d);
    float InvDistSq = 1 / DistSq;

    o.xyz = -2 * RadiusSq * InvDistSq * InvDistSq * d;
    o.w = RadiusSq * InvDistSq;

    return o;
}


SamplerState TriLinearSampler
{
    Filter = MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR;
    AddressU = WRAP;
    AddressV = WRAP;
};


// Vertex shader calculates field contributions at each grid vertex
SampleData SampleFieldVS(float3 Pos : POSITION)
{
    SampleData o;

    float3 WorldPos = mul(float4(Pos, 1), World).xyz;

    // Sum up contributions from all metaballs

    o.Field = 0;

    for (uint i = 0; i<NumMetaballs; i++)
    {
        //o.Field += WorldPos.y;
        o.Field += Metaball(WorldPos, Metaballs[i].xyz, Metaballs[i].w);


    }
    // Transform position and normals


    o.Pos = mul(float4(Pos.xyz, 1), WorldViewProj);
    o.Field.xyz = -normalize(mul(o.Field.xyz, ViewIT));  // we want normals in view space


    // Generate in-out flags

    return o;
}



SampleData PassThroughVS(SampleData IN)
{
    SampleData OUT;
    OUT = IN;
    return OUT;
}

// Estimate where isosurface intersects grid edge with endpoints v0, v1
SurfaceVertex CalcIntersection(SampleData v0, SampleData v1)
{
    SurfaceVertex o;

    // We're taking special care to generate bit-exact results regardless of traversal (v0,v1) or (v1, v0)

    float t = (2.0 - (v0.Field.w + v1.Field.w)) / (v1.Field.w - v0.Field.w);

    o.Pos = 0.5 * (t * (v1.Pos - v0.Pos) + (v1.Pos + v0.Pos));
    o.N = 0.5 * (t * (v1.Field.xyz - v0.Field.xyz) + (v1.Field.xyz + v0.Field.xyz));    

    float4 worldPos = mul(World, o.Pos);
    o.tex = worldPos.xy;

    return o;
}

// This struct stores vertex indices of up to 4 edges from the input tetrahedron. The GS code below 
// uses these indices to index into the input vertex set for interpolation along those edges. 
// It basically encodes topology for the output triangle strip (of up to 2 triangles).
struct TetrahedronIndices 
{ 
    uint4 e0; 
    uint4 e1; 
};

[MaxVertexCount(4)]
void TessellateTetrahedraGS(lineadj SampleData In[4], inout TriangleStream<SurfaceVertex> Stream)
{
    // construct index for this tetrahedron
    uint index = (uint(In[0].Field.w > 1) << 3) | (uint(In[1].Field.w > 1) << 2) | (uint(In[2].Field.w > 1) << 1) | uint(In[3].Field.w > 1);


    // don't bother if all vertices out or all vertices in
    if (index > 0 && index < 15)
    {
        uint4 e0 = EdgeTableGS[index].e0;
        uint4 e1 = EdgeTableGS[index].e1;

        // Emit a triangle
        Stream.Append( CalcIntersection(In[e0.x], In[e0.y]) );
        Stream.Append( CalcIntersection(In[e0.z], In[e0.w]) );
        Stream.Append( CalcIntersection(In[e1.x], In[e1.y]) );

        // Emit additional triangle, if necessary
        if (e1.z != 0) {
            Stream.Append( CalcIntersection(In[e1.z], In[e1.w]) );
        }

    }
}

TextureCube EnvMap;

float FresnelApprox(float3 I, float3 N)
{
    return R0Constant + R0Inv * pow(1.0 - dot(I, N), 5.0);
}

float4 ShadeSurfacePS( SurfaceVertex IN ) : SV_Target
{
    float4 Pos = GetWorldSpacePos( IN.Pos );

    float3 N = normalize(IN.N);
    float3 L1 = normalize(LightPos1 - Pos.xyz);
    float3 L2 = normalize(LightPos2 - Pos.xyz);
    float3 L3 = normalize(LightPos3 - Pos.xyz);
    float3 I = normalize(Pos.xyz);

    float3 R = reflect(I, N);

    float4 Reflected = EnvMap.Sample( TriLinearSampler, mul(ViewIT, R ) );

    float NdotL1 = max(0, dot(N, L1));
    float NdotL2 = max(0, dot(N, L2));
    float NdotL3 = max(0, dot(N, L3));

    float3 Color = NdotL1 * float3(1, 1, 1) + pow(max(dot(R, L1), 0), 32)
                    + NdotL2 * float3(0.65, 0.6, 0.45) + pow(max(dot(R, L2), 0), 32)
                    + NdotL3 * float3(0.7, 0.7, 0.8) + pow(max(dot(R, L3), 0), 32);

    return lerp(EnvMap.Sample( TriLinearSampler, mul(ViewIT, R) ), float4(Color, 1), FresnelApprox(I, N) * 0.05 );

}

float4 SimplePS( SurfaceVertex IN, uniform float4 color ) : SV_Target
{
    return color;
}

float4 DiffusePS( SurfaceVertex IN ) : SV_Target
{

    float4 AmbientColor = float4(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
    float AmbientIntensity = 0.2;

    float4 Kd = 0.5;
    float4 diffuseLight = 0.5;

    float4 Pos = GetWorldSpacePos( IN.Pos );
    float3 N = normalize(IN.N);
    float3 L1 = normalize(LightPos1 - Pos.xyz);
    float3 L2 = normalize(LightPos2 - Pos.xyz);
    float3 L3 = normalize(LightPos3 - Pos.xyz);

    float NdotL1 = max(0, dot(N, L1));
    float NdotL2 = max(0, dot(N, L2));
    float NdotL3 = max(0, dot(N, L3));

    float3 I = normalize(Pos.xyz);
    float3 V = normalize(-Pos.xyz);

    float4 vDiff = diffuseLight * Kd * NdotL1;
    float4 vDiff2 = diffuseLight * Kd * NdotL2;
    float4 vDiff3 = diffuseLight * Kd * NdotL3;

    float3 Color = vDiff + vDiff2 + vDiff3;
    float4 derp = rockTexture.Sample(RockSampler, IN.tex.xy);

    return lerp(derp ,float4(Color, 1), 0.5);
    //return lerp(NoiseTexture.Sample( NoiseSampler, IN.tex ), float4(Color, 1), FresnelApprox(V, N) * 0.05 );

    //return saturate(vDiff+vDiff2+vDiff3 + AmbientColor * AmbientIntensity);


}

DepthStencilState EnableDepthDSS
{
    DepthEnable = true;
    DepthWriteMask = 1;
};

RasterizerState WireFrameRS
{
    MultiSampleEnable = True;
    CullMode = None;
    FillMode = WireFrame;
};

RasterizerState SolidRS
{
    MultiSampleEnable = True;
    CullMode = None;
    FillMode = Solid;
};


technique10 MarchingTetrahedraWireFrame
{
    pass P0
    {
        SetRasterizerState( WireFrameRS );
        SetDepthStencilState( EnableDepthDSS, 0 );

        SetVertexShader( CompileShader( vs_4_0, SampleFieldVS() ) );
        SetGeometryShader( CompileShader( gs_4_0, TessellateTetrahedraGS() ) );
        SetPixelShader( CompileShader( ps_4_0, SimplePS( float4( 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 1 ) ) ) );
    }
}

// Tessellate isosurface in a single pass
technique10 MarchingTetrahedraSinglePassGS
{
    pass P0
    {
        SetRasterizerState( SolidRS );
        SetDepthStencilState( EnableDepthDSS, 0 );

        SetVertexShader( CompileShader( vs_4_0, SampleFieldVS() ) );
        SetGeometryShader( CompileShader( gs_4_0, TessellateTetrahedraGS() ) );
        SetPixelShader( CompileShader( ps_4_0, DiffusePS() ) );
    }
}

// Tessellate isosurface in two passes, streaming out VS results in-between
GeometryShader StreamOutGS = ConstructGSWithSO( CompileShader( vs_4_0, PassThroughVS() ), "SV_Position.xyzw; TEXCOORD0.xyzw" );

technique10 MarchingTetrahedraMultiPassGS
{
    pass P0
    {
        SetVertexShader( CompileShader( vs_4_0, SampleFieldVS() ) );
        SetGeometryShader( StreamOutGS );
        SetPixelShader( NULL );
    }

    pass P1
    {

        SetRasterizerState( SolidRS );
        SetDepthStencilState( EnableDepthDSS, 0 );

        SetVertexShader( CompileShader ( vs_4_0, PassThroughVS() ) );
        SetGeometryShader( CompileShader( gs_4_0, TessellateTetrahedraGS() ) );
        SetPixelShader( CompileShader( ps_4_0, DiffusePS() ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the rest of the .fx file

Comment: I have added the rest of the code.

Comment: I see that you are texturing it using some kind of square texture, I have textured isosurfaces using box projection texturing and volumetric textures, and the best is volumetric if you can get hold of formulas that are interesting enough and varied enough, and box projection is basically quite good, although it's a bit difficult to write, it takes all day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The texture coordinates are currently generated by multiplying the vertex position by the world matrix:

```
CalcIntersection()
....
    float4 worldPos = mul(World, o.Pos);
    o.tex = worldPos.xy;
....
```

So, the camera panning must be altering one of these inputs. Guessing that it's probably the world matrix (i.e. the camera panning is in fact the object being moved), try switching to a texture coordinate generating method that does not depend on the world matrix. e.g.:

```
CalcIntersection()
...
    o.tex = o.Pos.xy;
...
```

**Edit**: As that didn't work, it must be the position being modified by the camera panning, and looking at SampleFieldVS() there is a line which seems to be doing it:

```
o.Pos = mul(float4(Pos.xyz, 1), WorldViewProj);
```

So, what you need to do is save the position there before it gets modified. You'll have to save it in the SampleData, so add this at the end of the SampleData struct:

```
float2 tex1 : TEXCOORD1;
```

Then add the saving line at the end of SampleFieldVS()

```
o.tex1 = mul(float4(Pos.xyz, 0), World).xy;
```

And finally remove '*float4 worldPos = mul(World, o.Pos); o.tex = worldPos.xy;*' at the end of CalcIntersection() and replace with:

```
o.tex = 0.5 * (t * (v1.tex1 - v0.tex1) + (v1.tex1 + v0.tex1));
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this didn't fix it.
I would also just like to add that rotating the cameraview left and right also moves the position of the texture. It is like the texture is always centred on the screen if that makes sense.

I am not passing any texture coordinates from the .cpp file, I am purely generating them in the shader, is this correct?

Comment: Thank you so much, this has solved the problem for the single pass. However the multi-pass is still functioning incorrectly, is this because of the StreamOutGS?

Comment: Yes. Add `TEXCOORD1.xy;` to StreamOutGS. You will also have to update the cpp code in a few place: 1) Add another TEXCOORD element when calling CreateInputLayout(). Make sure you set it to index 1 and R32G32_FLOAT format. 2) Adjust the size of the stream output buffer for the new size of the SampleData struct. 3) And likewise change the stride size when calling IASetVertexBuffers()

Comment: Thank you so much. This has solved my problem entirely. I have also learnt a lot. Thanks.